# Как вызвать getServiceLocator() в invokable классе

Tags: php, zend2

Регистрирую `invokable` класс в `module.config.php`

```
'view_helpers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'iAmForm' => 'Application\View\Helper\IAmFormHelper',
    ),
),
```

Создаю `invokable` класс, в котором нужно получить доступ к сервису:

```
class IAmFormHelper extends AbstractHelper
{
    public function __invoke()
    {//это сейчас недоступно:
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $sessionContainer = $sm->get('Session\Model\SessionContainer');
        $userSession = $sessionContainer->getEntity();

        return new IAmForm($userSession);
    }
    //...
}
```

Как получить доступ к сервису, так, как это делается в Controller-классах?
*(речь идет о фреймворке zend2)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для доступа к `ServiceManager` нужно имплементировать `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface`:

```
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;

class IAmFormHelper extends AbstractHelper implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{
    protected $services;

    public function setServiceLocator( ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator )
    {
        $this->services = $serviceLocator;
    }
    public function getServiceLocator()
    {
        return $this->services;
    }
    public function __invoke()
    {
        //это сейчас доступно:
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $sessionContainer = $sm->get('Session\Model\SessionContainer');
        $userSession = $sessionContainer->getEntity();

        return new IAmForm($userSession);
    }
}
```

Или воспользоваться трейтом `ServiceLocatorAwareTrait`:

```
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;

class IAmFormHelper extends AbstractHelper implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{
    use ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;

    public function __invoke()
    {
        //это сейчас доступно:
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $sessionContainer = $sm->get('Session\Model\SessionContainer');
        $userSession = $sessionContainer->getEntity();

        return new IAmForm($userSession);
    }
}
```

И можешь спокойно вызывать `$this->getServiceLocator()`.

ПС:
при вызове `$this->getServiceLocator();` возвратит экземпляр `Zend\View\HelperPluginManager`
при вызове `$this->getServiceLocator()->getServiceLocator();` возвратит экземпляр `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager`